# objective c mute UILocalNotification when user making phone call

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, headset, in-call

I have an app that is registered for `UILocalNotification`, and the notification sound have a duration of 30 seconds, when user is making a phone call and the `fireDate` of the `UILocalNotification` at the same time with the call, the notification sound play in the headset and the user is not able to hear his voice call

im wondering if there is a way to mute the `UILocalNotification` if there is a running phone call

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [CTCallCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009604) ( the Core Telephony framework ) to register an event handler so your app gets notified when a call starts

> Use the CTCallCenter class to obtain a list of current cellular calls,
>   and to respond to state changes for calls such as from a dialing state
>   to a connected state. Such state changes are known as cellular call
>   events.

Something like:

```
CTCallCenter *callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];

...

...

callCenter.callEventHandler=^(CTCall* call)
{    
  if (call.callState == CTCallStateConnected) 
  {
    NSLog(@"Call has just been connected");
  }    
}
```

Comment: and how to do that?? before firing the local notification, during or after, describe more please

Comment: You should do some research on that class. I've edited my answer